# JPA orphanRemoval doesn't work on childs' orphans

Tags: java, jpa

I am having trouble deleting orphans of child element using JPA (sorry if it's not clear, see below).

I have a **Questionnaire** that contains a list of **Question** which contain a list of **Answer**

class Questionnaire :

```
public class Questionnaire {
   ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "questionnaire", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<>();
}
```

class Question :

```
public class Question {
   ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="questionnaire_id")
   private Questionnaire questionnaire;
}
```

class Answer :

```
public class Answer {
   ...
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="question_id")
   private Question question;
}
```

I'm using an AngularJs frontend with REST services.

I'm only making JPA save operation on *Questionnaire* and I want *questions* and *answers* to be inserted, updated or removed if needed.

Thanks to **CascadeType.ALL**, when I save a *Questionnaire* all *questions* and *answers* are correctly inserted and updated.

Thanks to **orphanRemoval = true**, when I save a *Questionnaire* with deleted *questions*, these deleted *questions* are correctly removed from database.

But this is not working for deleted *answers* : When I save a *Questionnaire* with *questions* containing deleted *answers*, these deleted *answers* aren't removed from database.

Any idea to help me ?
Thanks :)

Comment: On the face of what you've described, it looks like a bug in your provider, but you will have to debug a bit to see what exists in the objects after your merge call.  Verify that the object returned from from merge reflects what you expect - that the expected answers are no longer in the graph.  You will also need to check your model that something else isn't referencing the answers that might cause them to be resurrected - orphan removal should be considered only if they are privately owned objects, as those other references won't get cleaned up.

Comment: It might also be an issue of `equals/hashCode` implementation, especially if the questions happen to be updated and then removed from the collection.

Comment: In fact, my problem is solved.
I don't really know how, but it was not an issue on Java part as I didn't change anything to make it work.

I changed many things on frontend side (angularjs), so I think the problem was on the generated JSON...

Anyway, thank you for your help.